# Converting JScript to VB.NET - Questions

Tags: vb.net, md5, javascript

I'm trying to convert some functions written in JScript to VB.NET (I'm porting a classic ASP page to ASP.NET) and having issues as I'm not very familiar with JScript. I'm having issues with converting even the function declaration properly in VB.NET. In my converted code VS2008 is giving me an error saying "Array bounds can not be specified in type identifiers".  I don't know how to modify my function declaration to return an Array but ALSO accept an array as input as the JScript declaration does.  Any ideas?  Am I approaching this wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is one of the original JScript functions:

```
function binl2byt(binarray)
{
  var hex_tab = "0123456789abcdef";
  var bytarray = new Array(binarray.length * 4);
  var str = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
  {       
    bytarray[i] = (binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4) & 0xF) << 4 | binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8) & 0xF;
  }

  return bytarray;
}
```

Here is what I have in VB.NET so far:

```
Public Function binl2byt() As Array(byval binarray as array)
  Dim hex_tab As String = "0123456789abcdef"
  Dim bytarray() As Byte
  Dim str As String = ""

  For I As Integer = 0 To (bytarray.Length * 4) Step 1
    bytarray(I) = ((binarray(I >> 2) >> ((I Mod (4)) * 8 + 4) & Oxf) << 4) Or (binarray(I >> 2) >> ((I Mod (4) * 8) & OxF))
  Next

  Return bytarray
End Function
```

Comment: Also, for your knowledge, to pass arrays in and out of functions, you can do Public Function x(b() as Byte) as Byte() or whatever data type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this function, it is already there in .NET for you.

```
BitConverter.ToString(Bytes);
```

Where Bytes is your byte array.